# Little mistake in proof mean value theorem inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to proof the following inequality: $\cos x>1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for all $0<x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ given the following function: $g(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\cos x$.

My proof: Note that $g'(x)=\sin x-x$. It follows that for every $x>0$ there exists a $c\in ]0,x[$ such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} =g'(c)=\sin c-c.
\end{equation}
Now, noting that $g(0)=0$ and $\sin(c)<1 \implies \sin(c)-c<1$ gives us:
\begin{equation}
\frac{g(x)}{x} =\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\cos x}{x}<1.
\end{equation}
But now, the inequality that follows is $\cos x>1-\frac{x^2}{2}-x$ and not the desired one. Did i make a little mistake somewhere?

Comment: Since $g’ \lt 0$ for $x\gt 0$ and $g(0)=0$,$ g(x) \lt 0$ for $x\gt 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inequality $\sin x<x$ for all $0<x\leq \pi/2$ and all your troubles are gone.

Comment: Yup, that's really simple :) ! Thanks. Can i just use that inequality / how would i proof it?

Comment: I think i managed sin x < x with the mean value theorem as well.